# condition IF inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have this code:

```
$data['products'][] = array(
    'percent'     => sprintf($this->language->get('-%s'), (round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price']) * 100 ,0 ))) . ' %',
    'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
    'thumb'       => $image,
    'name'        => $result['name'],
    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
    'price'       => $price,
    'special'     => $special,
    'tax'         => $tax,
    'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
    'rating'      => $result['rating'],
    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
);
```

I need to make condition if `price===0`, then `percent===0`. Pls help.

Comment: Why not outside the array? Like `if($price === 0) $percent = 0;` just before your array.

Comment: Be aware that your approach will lead to unreadable code

Comment: You have already demonstrated that you know how to write an inline conditional statement (like spoonisback has written out for you) @ `minimum`.  Why are you asking how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the ternary operator:

```
[
    ....,
    'percent'     => ($price === 0) ? 0 : sprintf($this->language->get('-%s'), (round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price']) * 100 ,0 ))) . ' %',
    ....
]
```